# Inheritance not working in PHP

Tags: php, class, inheritance, abstract

I have got this structure:

```
abstract class Android {
    public function __construct() {

    }

    public abstract function cost();

    public function get_model(){
        return "unkown model";
    }
}

class HTC extends Android {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model= "HTC";
    }

    public function get_model() {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public function cost() {
        return 500;
    }
}

abstract class FeaturesDecorator extends Android {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public abstract function get_description();
}

class VideoCamera extends FeaturesDecorator {
    private $android;

    public function __construct($android) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->android=$android;
    }

    public function get_description() {
         return $this->android->get_model()." plus a video camera, ";
    }

    public function cost() {
        return 200 + $this->android->cost();
    }
}

class BigScreenSize extends FeaturesDecorator {
    private $android;

    public function __construct($android) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->android=$android;
    }

    public function get_description() {
        return $this->android->get_model()." plus a big size screen, ";  
    }

    public function cost() {
        return 100 + $this->android->cost();
    }
}
```

After applying the following pattern:

```
$android2 = new HTC();
$android2 = new BigScreenSize($android2);
$android2 = new LongLastingBattery($android2);

echo "<br/><br/>You have bought ".$android2->get_description()." for $".$android2->cost();
```

I get

> You have bought Unkown brand plus a long lasting battery, for $650

**Again:**

I wonder why I get `Unknown brand` instead of `HTC` from `get_model()` called by `get_description()`, **while `$650` is being calculated correctly**.

Comment: You should take a look at [this](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/07/oop-vs-procedural-code.html) blog article. Using `abstract class` in this approach makes it cry out for multi-inheritance which is not supported in PHP (at least not in this way). This code needs refactoring and taking a different approach than `abstract class`.

Answer (score 0):

When i first tested your code, php told me that the class `LongLastingBattery` does not exist, which is correct - it doesn't. I assume you meant `VideoCamera`; so your main function in my answer will begin with this:

```
$android2 = new HTC();
$android2 = new BigScreenSize($android2);
$android2 = new VideoCamera($android2);
```

Your problem is that you are simply confusing the two methods `get_description()` and `get_model()`: You first call get_description() on the VideoCamera instance. There you have $this->android->get_model() where $this->android is an instance of BigScreenSize. The class BigScreenSize does not override the method get_model(). BigScreenSize extends FeaturesDecorator, that does not override this method either but extends Android, that has this method and returns `"unknown model"`.

To overcome this problem you could change `$this->android->get_model()` into `$this->android->get_description()` in both VideoCamera and BigScreenSize and rename the get_model() method in both Android and HTC into get_description(). Finally, you have to change FeaturesDecorator into this:

```
abstract class FeaturesDecorator extends Android {}
```

Then you'll get this:

```
<br/><br/>You have bought HTC plus a big size screen,  plus a video camera,  for $800
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `FeatureDecorator` inherits from `Android`, not from `HTC`. So the first time you are adding decoration, `$android2` will be of type `Android` instead of the previous type of `HTC`.

Maybe you meant the following:

```
abstract class FeaturesDecorator extends HTC {
  // ...
}
```

That should give you the correct output for your example.

---

**edit** you could move your `model` member variable to the `Android` class; should work as well:

```
abstract class Android {
  protected $model = "unknown model";

  public function get_model() {
    return $this->model;
  }
}
```

That way `model` is directly stored within `Android`, can be set from all child classes, and can be retrieved from any other class that holds a reference to an  `Android` object.

Comment: Yeah, but htc has got the Android abstract class which has get_model... that can be overriden by htc..

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd: yes, it can be overriden by `HTC`, but your decorators do not extend `HTC` – they only extend `Android`. Neither `Android` nor `FeatureDecorator` have knowledge of `HTC`. One thing you could do is to store your `model` member variable in `Android` instead of `HTC`, that could work too.

Answer (score -1):

```
$android1=new HTC();
$android2=new BigScreenSize($android1);
$android3=new VideoCamera($android2);
```

doing a var_dump on $android2 and 3 will give you the objects they hold (had to change to videocamera as the battery class is not present in the code you provided) and android3 holds the bigscreensize object not the htc, hence the 'unknown'. If you want to obtain your result (the 'HTC') you have to (make the $android public not private first) and

```
echo $android3->android->get_description();
```

or as per your example (still making $android public in your classes)

```
echo $android2->android->get_description();
```

Applying those changes gives me:

> You have bought HTC plus a big size screen, for $800

In the end I still hold my initial thought that you should tinker with the approach you took. Maybe add a method that would obtain the $model from it's parent and use it in a constructor. This way you can keep track of a model and use the local property. (In my example above videocamera tries to access bigscreensize->get_model() when executing get_description(), this method does not exist in bigscreensize, but does in android which is a parent of bigscreensize's parent. Inheritance works here just fine. Notice that your decorators have no idea of htc class existance, so unless you provide a method for all of the decorators to access/pass the 'model' variable. You will have no access to it passed the first decorator. cost() works because it is present in every class.

I should have read the question before I answered last night. Sorry.

Comment: whats the difference. The cost() method works that way, but get_description ,,,doesnt..why?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd I hope I've been of more help this time.